# Utilizando o código abaixo, porque eu só estou coletando os dados da última página do Loop?

Tags: xml, r, loop

```
rm(list=ls())
options(warn=-1)
library("RCurl")
library("XML")

baseurl <- "http://www.gmbahia.ufba.br/index.php/gmbahia/issue/archive?issuesPage=XX#issues"
dados <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:29){
      print(i)
      url <- gsub("XX", i, baseurl)
      url <- xmlRoot(htmlParse(readLines(url)))
      links <- getNodeSet(url, "//a")}

## Links das Teses
links.teses <- xmlSApply(links, xmlGetAttr, name = "href")
links.teses <- grep("view", links.teses, value = T)
links.teses

## Nomes das Edições
teses.titulos <- xmlSApply(links, xmlValue)
teses.titulos <- grep("de", teses.titulos, value = T)
teses.titulos

dados <- rbind(teses.titulos, links.teses)} 
View(dados)
```

Comment: formatei o seu código e também fiz a inclusão da tag R, já que você não colocou (estou aguardando algum revisor aprovar). De qualquer maneira, revise o código postado, pois o for abre, mas não fecha. Aproveite para descrever melhor o seu problema, quem sabe um pouco do algoritmo. Isso vai ajudar a sua pergunta a ter mais atenção da comunidade. Mostrar  esforço e cuidado ao formatar uma pergunta faz bem. :-)

Comment: Obrigado Cantoni, mesmo fechando o for, eu só pego as últimas paginas.

Comment: Creio já ter a resposta para a sua pergunta. Estou testando. Dá uma editada nela, mostrando onde o for começa e termina. Eu já vi aqui, mas é importante ficar documentado. Aproveita e faz uma breve descrição do que você está tentando fazer. Postar códigos assim sem dizer nada não é legal. Aguardo aqui para postar a resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja a sugestão de código abaixo. Agora está funcionando. O loop precisava ser fechado (como @cantoni já tinha dito). Mas o problema que você reportava tinha a ver com o fato de que você estava sobre-escrevendo os dados coletados a cada iteração do for.

O que você quer é adicionar linhas ao banco de dados. Então tem que concatenar os dados já existentes com os novos. Ou seja: o objeto "dados" tem que ser citado dentro do rbind. É uma operação recursiva: o novo valor desse data.frame é igual ao antigo mais as atualizações.

Mas antes disso, você tem que tranformar os vetores "teses.titulos" e "links.teses" em duas colunas -- o que eu fiz abaixo com o cbind.

```
# rm(list=ls()) # não é legal colocar no StackOverFlow essa linha...
# options(warn=-1) #não é legal desativar todos os avisos. Coloquei essa opção dentro do comando readLines (abaixo)
#library("RCurl") # desativei -- esse pacote não está sendo usado
library("XML")

baseurl <- "http://www.gmbahia.ufba.br/index.php/gmbahia/issue/archive?issuesPage=XX#issues"

dados <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:10){
  print(i)
  url <- gsub("XX", i, baseurl)
  url <- xmlRoot(htmlParse(readLines(url, warn = F))) # adicionei a opcao de remover avisos aqui
  links <- getNodeSet(url, "//h4/a") #adicionei h4 aqui -- pra pegar só os links de teses

  ## Links das Teses
  links.teses <- xmlSApply(links, xmlGetAttr, name = "href")
  #links.teses <- grep("view", links.teses, value = T) #desativei - linha desnecessária
  #links.teses  #desativei - linha desnecessária

  ## Nomes das Edições
  teses.titulos <- xmlSApply(links, xmlValue)
  #teses.titulos <- grep("de", teses.titulos, value = T) #desativei - linha desnecessária
  #teses.titulos #desativei - linha desnecessária
  dados <- rbind(dados, cbind(teses.titulos, links.teses)) #aqui estava o erro
  }
```

Comment: Fiz exatamente isso, mas estava aguardando um posicionamento do autor da pergunta. :-)